# Doctrine2 Get Table Relations

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need to get one/many To one/many relations informations from an entity with Doctrine2

With Doctrine1 I can do :

```
Doctrine::getTable('Article')->getRelations();
```

How to do it with Doctrine2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory` for this.
`$metaData = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('your_classname')`